# should I reuse mysql connect

Tags: mysql

I have program that constantly query a mysql server. Each time I access the server I made a connection then query it. I wonder if I can actually save time by reuse the same connection and only reconnect when the connection is closed. Given that I can fit many of my queries within the duration of connection timeout and my program has only one thread.

Comment: What kind of program is it? Where is it running? Opening a connection *before every query* is most likely unnecessary, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes by all means, re-use the connection!

If you are also doing updates/delete/inserts through that connection make sure you commit (or rollback) you transactions properly so that once you are "done" with the connection, it is left in a clean state.

Another option would be to use a connection pooler.

Answer (score 3):

yes - this is a good idea.

remember to use the timeout so you don't leave connections open permanently.

also, remember to close it when the program exits. (even after exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should reuse the connection, within reason. Don't leave a connection open indefinitely, but you can batch your queries together so that you get everything done, and then close it immediately afterwards.

Leaving a connection open too long means that under high traffic you might hit the maximum number of possible connections to your server.

Reconnecting often is just slow, causes a lot of unnecessary chatter, and is simply a waste.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you should look into using **mysql_pconnect** function which will create persistent connection to the database. You can read about it here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php

Comment: This is PHP code, which the author of the question has not specified is his/her language. Probably a good guess on your part, but at this point the question is just theory.

Comment: Long night. Didn't notice that no language was specified :)

Comment: Thanks. I would like to have more general answer though. Is this for mysql in general or just php

Comment: It works both ways. Example I've provided is PHP-specific but most MySQL APIs will support persistent connections. Some of them do it transparently and some of them (like in PHP) you would have to call specifically.